# Bean Valiation @Size or something custom similar to it for List<Integer>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a field `private List<Integer> numbersList14;` and i need to validate size of this list.

This list must be empty or it must contain exactly 5 elements.
I tried to do this like that:

```java
  @Size(min=5, max=5)
            private List<Integer> numbersList14;

or

  @Capacity(min=0, max=5)
           private List<Integer> numbersList14;
```

@Capacity is a custom validator which i've written, but neither @Size nor @Capacity is working.

Here is @PostMapping in Conroller:

```java
  @PostMapping("/validate_regon")
    public String submitRegon(@Validated @ModelAttribute("numbersList") Regon regon, BindingResult bindingResult)  {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("There were errors");
            bindingResult.getAllErrors().forEach(error -> {
                System.out.println(error.getObjectName() + " " + error.getDefaultMessage());
            });
            return "regon_form";


        }else {

            return "/regon_validated";

        }
    }
```

Here is my @interface Capacity.java

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CapacityValidator.class)
@Target( {ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Capacity {

    String message() default "All fields must be filled or all of them must be empty!";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    int min();
    int max();
}
```

And here is CapacityValidator.java

```java
public class CapacityValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Capacity, List<Integer>> {

    private int min;
    private int max;


    @Override
    public void initialize(Capacity constraintAnnotation) {
        this.min = constraintAnnotation.min();
        this.max = constraintAnnotation.max();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<Integer> list, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return list.size() == this.max || list.size() == this.min;
    }

}
```

**Edit:**
I deleted hibernate-validator from my pom.xml and `@Capacity` is  working now, but it's showing errors only in console and not Thymeleaf.
All oother annotations like `@NotNull` or `@PositiveOrZero` are showing errors in both - console and Thymeleaf.
Why is this happening?

Comment: You're using it as Size, but the class is Capacity.

Comment: I tried @Capacity(min=0, max=5) private List<Integer> numbersList14; too and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency? Don't use the plain `hibernate-validator` as you probaly try to use version 7 which isn't compatible (it is for JakartaEE not JavaEE).

Comment: I have spring-boot-starter-validation as a dependency and i had hibernate-validator too. I deleted hibernate-validator from my pom.xml and `@Capacity` is  working now, but it's showing errors only in console and not Thymeleaf. All oother annotations like `@NotNull `or `@PositiveOrZero` are showing errors in both - console and Thymeleaf.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

@Size do work with Collection, and this is the proof (I use lombok in this example):

```
@Builder
@Validated
@Getter
class Dummy {

    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    private List<Integer> intList;
}
```

Assuming you have a validtion implementation on your classpath let's say hibernate-validator maven dependency, you can check it by a simple junit test :

```
@Test
    public void test() {
        List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
        integerList.add(1);

        Dummy dummy = Dummy.builder().intList(integerList).build();

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Dummy>> violations = validator.validate(dummy);

        Assertions.assertThat(violations.isEmpty());

        dummy.getIntList().add(2);

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Dummy>> violations2 = validator.validate(dummy);

        Assertions.assertThat(violations2.isEmpty()).isFalse();
        for (ConstraintViolation<Dummy> violation : violations2) {
           System.err.println (violation.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And, you should use **@Valid** to validate the param, not @Validated.

Comment: I know it should work, but it doesn't for me. My controller returns "/regon_validated" when it should display an error so the program behaves as if the annotations Size or Capacity do not exists.  Could it be caused by Google Guava which i use for the List?

Comment: try to use Valid annotation on controller method param, with a simple Size annotation.

Comment: And i used Valid and not Validated all the time. Just changed it for test and forgot to change it back before adding the code here. Neither Valid nor Validated has any effect in this case.

Comment: did you add Validated annotation on you Regon class ?

Comment: I did and it has no effect too.  The program "recognizes" te annotations only if i do something like this:  private List<@Size(min=5, max=5) Integer> numbersList14; but here it validates the individual elements of the List and not the entire list.